# I need to split a series of 'varchar' responses so that it would appear as a new row when creating a DataTable?

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

What I need to be able to do is to take the responses form an online questionnaire that are stored on the database, and display them as a table on a website, which so far I have done, and it looks like this:

```
    ||User Id |Group   | Q1                 | Q2            | Q3    | Q4   |...
    | 1234    |no group| 30/06/14, 25/08/14,| gs,gm, cl&h   | either|s1    |...
    |         |        | 27/07/14           |               |       |      |...
```

I now need to display the existing data in a new way.  The information in the cells need to be split so that where there are multiple bits of information in a cell, a new row is created.  Not sure the best way to describe it, but using the above as an example, I need it to look like this:

```
||User Id |Group   | Q1      | Q2   | Q3    | Q4   |...
| 1234    |no group| 30/06/14| gs   | either|s1    |...
| 1234    |no group| 25/08/14| gm   | either|s1    |...
| 1234    |no group| 27/07/14| cl&h | either|s1    |...
```

Basically so that the same UserID, Group etc are used in each row, but each different Q1, Q2, etc.

This is the code that I have used so far to achieve the top example.

```
'
' sql to get data
    sql = "select * from TABLE where (datestamp > '" & startDate & "') AND (datestamp < '" & endDate & "') ORDER BY datestamp"

Set fieldTitles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
fieldTitles.Add "userID", "User ID"
fieldTitles.Add "grp", "Group"
fieldTitles.Add "q1", "Q1"
fieldTitles.Add "q2", "Q2"
fieldTitles.Add "q3", "Q3"
fieldTitles.Add "q4", "Q4"
fieldTitles.Add "q5", "Q5"
fieldTitles.Add "q6", "Q6"
fieldTitles.Add "q7", "Q7"
fieldTitles.Add "q8", "Q8"
fieldTitles.Add "q9", "Q9"
fieldTitles.Add "qOrder1", "qOrder1"
fieldTitles.Add "qOrder2", "qOrder2"
fieldTitles.Add "qOrder3", "qOrder3"
fieldTitles.Add "qOrder4", "qOrder4"
fieldTitles.Add "datestamp", "Date Stamp"
fieldTitles.Add "Qid", "Qid"
fieldTitles.add "y5grp", "Year 5 Group"

' get the table html
dataString = createDataTableSQL(fieldTitles, sql, "")
```

I have been trying to think of a way using 'Left(string,length)' to remove beginning text and duplicating the rows, but I can't consistantly do that if the strings are different lengths (like in Q2).  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm really trying ... but ... is your sample of the first table really the source of the second table? I doubt it... Is for example the data in Q1 not 30/06/14, 25/08/14? Why I'm asking is 'what' should be duplicated? if 'the multiple values' are concentrated in 1 column I have a picture in my head, but what if there a multiple values in multiple columns like Q1 and Q2, what should the end result look like?

Comment: Apologies, too many hours of coding! I had put the wrong dates in the first table.  It's corrected now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Purely to show you the method, this does what your looking for, not sure I agree that your storing the data in the correct way to start with, but hope this helps

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ROWID,
trim(
regexp_substr(Q2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
) decoded
FROM
(
select
'1234' as USER_ID,
'NO GROUP' as "GROUP",
'30/06/14, 25/08/14, 27/07/14' as Q1,
'qs,gm, cl&h' as Q2,
'either' as Q3,
's1' as Q4
from
dual
) X CONNECT BY trim(
regexp_substr(Q2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
ROWID;
```